# Reference interface field in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, primeng

In typescript i have Command interface that has a Supplier :

```
export interface Command {
  supplier?: Supplier;
}

export interface Supplier {
  id?: number;
  name: String;
}
```

I'm trying to display supplier's name in angular inputtext before i select a supplier, but i get the error

> error command.supplier is undefined

```
<input id="input" type="text" size="30" pInputText [(ngModel)]="command.supplier.name">
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="command?.supplier?.name"`

Comment: i get the following error : Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 37 in [operationArticle?.fournisseur?.name=$event]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize it in your component like :-

```
public component = {
   supplier: {
       id: null,
       name: null
   }
};
```

or use in template with safe traversal operator :-

```
<input id="input" type="text" size="30" pInputText [(ngModel)]="command.supplier.name">
```

Comment: that didn't work i get the following error : Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 37 in [operationArticle?.fournisseur?.name=$event]